# How to close enumerated file?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, enumerator, loops

Say, in an action I have:

```
val linesEnu = {
    val is = new java.io.FileInputStream(path)
    val isr = new java.io.InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")
    val br = new java.io.BufferedReader(isr)
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    val rows: scala.collection.Iterator[String] = br.lines.iterator
    Enumerator.enumerate(rows)
}

Ok.feed(linesEnu).as(HTML)
```

How to close readers/streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `onDoneEnumerating` callback that functions like `finally` (will always be called whether or not the `Enumerator` fails). You can close the streams there.

```
val linesEnu = {
    val is = new java.io.FileInputStream(path)
    val isr = new java.io.InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")
    val br = new java.io.BufferedReader(isr)
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    val rows: scala.collection.Iterator[String] = br.lines.iterator
    Enumerator.enumerate(rows).onDoneEnumerating {
        is.close()
        // ... Anything else you want to execute when the Enumerator finishes.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The IO tools provided by `Enumerator` give you this kind of resource management out of the box—e.g. if you create an enumerator with `fromStream`, the stream is guaranteed to get closed after running (even if you only read a single line, etc.).

So for example you could write the following:

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee._

val splitByNl = Enumeratee.grouped(
  Traversable.splitOnceAt[Array[Byte], Byte](_ != '\n'.toByte) &>>
  Iteratee.consume()
) compose Enumeratee.map(new String(_, "UTF-8"))

def fileLines(path: String): Enumerator[String] =
  Enumerator.fromStream(new java.io.FileInputStream(path)).through(splitByNl)
```

It's a shame that the library doesn't provide a `linesFromStream` out of the box, but I personally would still prefer to use `fromStream` with hand-rolled splitting, etc. over using an iterator and providing my own resource management.

Comment: Travis, thanks for the way - I tried it also augmenting it with plenty of filters and maps applied to every string I have in real code. In result I have got ~2.5 slower stream in comparison with that stream using java iterators. Are you using any performance tuning?